# How to delete certificate from Keychain Access?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, keychain

When I try to delete certificate in **Keychain Access** I get following error

`An error occurred while deleting "iPhone Destribution:***." cssmerr_dl_invalid_record_uid keychain`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Keychain Access* menu is a *Keychain First Aid item*.

Perhaps it will fix the problem for you?

EDIT: As per comments, also try a system restart after using keychain first aid.

Comment: @ofirbt you shouldn't accept an answer unless it actually solved the problem, or at least helped you solve it. Feel free to un-accept my answer if it didn't work.

Comment: @Abhi Beckert - after a system restart your solution actually did the trick. tnx!